# Maven scope in plugin' dependencies

Tags: maven-3

I am using Maven 3.x (3.2.5) and my project use the `maven-antrun-plugin` with additional dependencies. While I understand the principle behind, I have trouble understanding the use of `<scope />` in this case:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.8</version>
  <!-- executions -->
  <dependencies>
    ... 
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.17</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    ...
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

I am depending upon `mysql-connector-java` with a `runtime` scope, whereas other dependencies use default (`compile`) scope.

The `maven-antrun-plugin` is used to do something to various database (hence the dependency). However, since the project is not tied to a specific JDBC Driver, the driver is not added to the project dependencies. The Ant task runs with several driver as dependencies since it *may* use such database depending on the configuration (eg: one could use `jdbc:mysql`, other `jdbc:oracle:thin`, etc...).

To my understanding, since the plugin executes, maven ignore the scope.

Is that true ?

Note: I've read the [Maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_dependencies_Tag), and this point is not discussed. I'm pretty sure it is ignored but I'd like insight before.

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope

Comment: The only place where "plugin" is referenced is on the menu. This explain the kind of scope (which I know), not if they are used for dependencies provided to plugin (which I'm looking for). So unless I've missed something, I don't see how this link should help me?

Comment: Firstly, what is the objective of defining the mysql-connector-java as part of plugin dependencies ? As per doc, You could configure the dependencies of the Build plugins, commonly to use a more recent dependency version.

Comment: This is legacy code but the driver is here because we don't want to depend on it (see updated question) and I'm not trying to move the dependencies outside the plugin. I'm trying to figure out _what was the intent in putting the scope_.